# I'm stuck on a 'glibc detected an invalid stdio handle' how to find the source?

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm trying to write a program that recovers images from a `.raw` file for some online course assignment but I have come across this obscure error

> glibc detected an invalid stdio handle aborted

Now I've found some similar question on the site but none of them were similar to mine.

The problem starts at line 53 where I try to make a JPEG with a file pointer, I write some stuff to it from the raw file and then try to close the file using `fclose`, and that's exactly where the interrupt occurs, on line 60 I get the said error. I have checked the image pointer and it's not NULL so I don't understand what's wrong with the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
 typedef unsigned char BYTE;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Invalid Argument Count!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *card=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (card==NULL)
    {
        printf("%s Could Not Be Read!\n",argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }
    //get size
    fseek(card,0,SEEK_END);
    int size_bytes=ftell(card);
    //assuming FAT filesystem 
    int block_starts[size_bytes/512];
    for (int i=0;i<size_bytes/512;i++)
    {
        block_starts[i]=i*512;
    }
    int i=0;
    int k=0;
    int j;
    BYTE *signature=malloc(4*sizeof(BYTE));
    BYTE *signature_2=malloc(4*sizeof(BYTE));
    char buff[8];
    if ((signature==NULL)||(signature_2==NULL))
    {
        printf("Not Enough Memory!\n");
        return 3;
    }
    //JPEG condition
    while (i<=size_bytes/512)
    {
        j=i+1;
        fseek(card,block_starts[i],SEEK_SET);
        fread(signature,sizeof(BYTE),4,card);
        if ((*signature==0xff)&&(*(signature+1)==0xd8)&&(*(signature+2)==0xff)&&(0xe0<=*(signature+3))&&(*(signature+3)<=0xef))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                fseek(card,block_starts[j],SEEK_SET);
                fread(signature_2,sizeof(BYTE),4,card);
                if((*signature==0xff)&&(*(signature+1)==0xd8)&&(*(signature+2)==0xff)&&(0xe0<=*(signature+3))&&(*(signature+3)<=0xef))
                {
                    fseek(card,block_starts[i],SEEK_SET);
                    sprintf(buff,"%03i.jpg",k);
                    FILE *image=fopen(buff,"w");
                    if (image==NULL)
                    {
                        printf("%s Could Not Be Created!\n",buff);
                        return 1;
                    }
                    fread(image,sizeof(BYTE),(j-i)*512,card);
                    fclose(image);
                    k++;
                    i=j;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
    fclose(card);
    free(signature);
    free(signature_2);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is what I get from the compiler

> Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle
> Aborted (core dumped)

As others have pointed out in the comments I was passing two file pointer to `fread` while it should have been a buffer and a file pointer

Comment: `FILE *image=fopen(buff,"w"); fread(image,sizeof(BYTE),(j-i)*512,card);` The first arg to `fread` is supposed to be the buffer to read into. Not a file pointer as you are giving it.

Comment: ... and `while (i <= size_bytes / 512)` + `fseek(card, block_starts[i], SEEK_SET);` will access `block_starts`  out of bounds. You probably want `while (i < size_bytes / 512)`

Comment: so ypu're saying I should pass something other than the image pointer like an intermediary buffer and then write that buffer to the image ?

Comment: yeah thx ted i just noticed that!

Comment: Unrelated: `sizeof(unsigned char)` is defined to be `1` so `sizeof(BYTE)` is too.

Comment: Re: `fread(image, sizeof(BYTE), (j - i) * 512, card);` - you can't read from one file stream and write to another file stream like this. `fread` to a buffer and `fwrite` from that buffer.

Comment: so I just read the documentation but I still don't get it like should line 59 be '''fread(card,sizeof(BYTE),(j-i)*512,imnage);'''

Comment: oh so like that intermediary buffer then thx